# How to create a catkin workspace through python script?

Tags: ros, catkin.workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create catkin workspace and packages through python script instead of the terminal. Any chance anybody tried it? if yes, please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259175/how-to-create-a-catkin-workspace-through-python-script?/) by [YusraAzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30010/yusraazhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes, for sure, you can with python execute the same commands in a scrypt automatically as if you were typing those by hand on a terminal, just refer to the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) if you need more specific info

you need to import the os lib and then invoke the os.system

example:

```
import os
cmd = 'mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src'
os.system(cmd)

os.system('catkin_make')
```

[python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0